# #1442 - Can't update table 'sale_price' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the same table before inserting new row in the table.
I want to set the status of all previous rows with the same product_id to 0 and after that insert new row with the status 1....Please help. here is my code written mysql..

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `priceStatusUpdate`//
CREATE TRIGGER `priceStatusUpdate` BEFORE INSERT ON `sale_price`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE sale_price 
  SET status=0
  WHERE product_id=new.product_id;
END
//
```

Comment: Where did you read that triggers work this way?

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName (IN p_product_id)
BEGIN
UPDATE sale_price SET status = 0 WHERE product_id = p_product_id;
INSERT INTO sale_price (product_id) VALUES (p_product_id);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call it with

```
CALL procedureName(1);
```

Comment: How is the procedure invoked?

Comment: What do you mean with how it is invoked? You use it instead of inserting into the table and call it like I posted, of course extended by the other columns.

Comment: still not working.....i am calling this procedure in my trigger but same error occur...

Comment: You need to drop the trigger of course :) This procedure won't produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `priceStatusUpdate`//
CREATE TRIGGER `priceStatusUpdate` BEFORE INSERT ON `sale_price`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.status= 0;
END
```